# How to create .txt file with variables when pybot fails

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework

[image: No Description Provided]  I have scenario where text file i need to create when pybot fails. When test case fails it should trigger a text file which should be pickup by jenkins downstream job and update it's environmental variable

When job fails i am making downstream job Test-Deployment run as shown in figure. I also need to pass one file on failure which updates environmental variable

Comment: You are going to need to show what you have tried and the relevant parts of your code in order for us to be able to help =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a [suite teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown) keyword that writes to the file. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           OperatingSystem
Suite Teardown    Save variables on failure

*** Test Case ***
Example
    fail    trigger saving of variables

*** Keywords ***
Save variables on failure
    run keyword if any tests failed    save variables to file

Save variables to file
    append to file    /tmp/variables.txt    export FOO='this is foo'\n
    append to file    /tmp/variables.txt    export BAR='this is bar'\n
```

A slightly more complex example is to create a python module that can be used as a [listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface), and write the file when pybot finishes.

For example, the python module could look like this:

```
class TestMonitor(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self

    def end_suite(self, name, attrs):
        if attrs['id'] == "s1" and attrs['status'] == "FAIL":
            with open("/tmp/variables.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write("export FOO='this is foo'\n")
                f.write("export BAR='this is bar\n")
```

You import this into your suite the way you import any other library. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           TestMonitor

*** Test Case ***
Example
    fail    trigger saving of variables
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for "Trigger even if the build fails" when you're creating the jenkins job.

[image: Trigger build]
<sub>(source: [bristiel.com](http://laurent.bristiel.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/trigger_build.png))</sub>

Read this blog post for the full context:
http://laurent.bristiel.com/create-jenkins-job-for-robot-framework/

EDIT:

To log environment variables on stderr you can do something like this:

```
import os
import sys
class Proxy():
    def __init__(self,out):
        self.out=out
    def write(self,msg):
        self.out.write(msg)
        exists=os.path.isfile("environ vars.txt")
        with open("environ vars.txt",'a' if exists else 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(os.environ))

sys.stderr=Proxy(sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Azeezah this we can achieve using trigger parameterized build on other projects. My problem is how to create a file when build is failed so that dowstream job can take this and update environmental variable

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Jenkins, so I don't know how you would distinguish when a build fails programmatically.  Just writing to a file is simple: `f=open("filename.txt","w"); f.write("failed");f.close()`

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you might log environment variables if errors are streamed to stderr.